# How to set a flag to indicate when all threads are done running

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering if anyone had information regarding how to set a flag to indicate when all the threads are done running?

I have 7 threads that run concurrently but I need to set a flag to show when all of them are finished to run a method to update the database table so it can switch to the other service. This is the first time I am using threads so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: You could use a `CountDownLatch` or `CyclicBarrier`

Comment: Or just call `join()` on each of them in turn...

Comment: You could call join() from the main thread..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `CountDownLatch`. It will full fill your requirement, What you have to do is, create an instance of CountDownLatch with `count value` equal to the number of threads. Start all the thread and call `await` method in main thread. Have the CountDownLatch object reference in all the threads and call the `countDown` method in each thread after completing its own job. For each countDown method, the CountDownLatch count value will get decrement. Once it reaches to `zero` the method where await is called will get wake-up. `Note if any one of your thread fails to call countDown then await will never get wake-up`.

Try this for your reference, 
http://www.java-redefined.com/p/java-count.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the `join` method to wait for each thread to finish execution.

```
for (Thread t : threads) {
     t.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using threads directly, check out [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).  Depending on how complex your workflow is, you may prefer the [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).